# How to use href.replace in extjs

Tags: javascript, regex

how to use href.replace in extjs

This is my sample:

```
'iconCls': 'icon_' + href.replace(/[^.]+\./, '')

href= http://localhost:1649/SFM/Default.aspx#/SFM/config/release_history.png
```

Now i want to get text `"release_history.png"`, How i get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the filename, it's probably easier to do:

```
var href = "http://localhost:1649/SFM/Default.aspx#/SFM/config/release_history.png";
var iconCls = 'icon_' + href.split('/').pop();
```

**Update**

To get the filename without the extension, you can do something similar:

```
var filename = "release_history.png";
var without_ext = filename.split('.');

// Get rid of the extension
without_ext.pop()

// Join the filename back together, in case
// there were any other periods in the filename
// and to get a string
without_ext = without_ext.join('.')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, one more question how to i get text "release_history.png" without ".png"

Answer (score 0):

some regex solutions (regex including `/` delimiter)

as in your example code match the start of the url that can be dropped

```
href.replace(/^.*\//, '')
```

or use a regex to get the last part of the url that you want to keep

```
/(?<=\/)[^.\/]+\.[^.]+$/
```

**update**

or get the icon name without `.png` (this is using lookbehind and lookahead feature of regex)

```
(?<=\/)[^.\/]+(?=\.png)
```

Not all flavors of regex support all lookaround reatures and I think Javascript only supports lookahead. so probably your solution is this:

```
[^.\/]+(?=\.png)
```

code examples here:
http://www.myregextester.com/?r=6acb5d23 
http://www.myregextester.com/?r=b0a88a0a

Comment: thanks for your answer, one more question how to i get text "release_history.png" without ".png"

Comment: you can try `/(?<=\/)[^.\/]+(?=\.png)/`